# Who are active researchers in the scheduling theory?

Tags: scheduling

I have an interest in a postdoc on scheduling problems but I cannot find many researchers who are actively involved in this. Any help?

Comment: I guess this is not a research level technical question which explains the down voting. Perhaps a different forum exists for this question?

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic here.  This site is for *technical* questions about computer science theory.  (The question has many other issues: it calls for a big list, which often doesn't work so well on this site format; answers will go out of date; the question shows no evidence of research or effort before asking; and if the site permitted this kind of question, it might be inundated with variants of this for every subfield of CS theory.)

Answer (score 6):

It could be useful to look at the list of participants of recent Dagstuhl seminars on scheduling

http://www.dagstuhl.de/program/calendar/partlist/?semnr=13111

http://www.dagstuhl.de/program/calendar/partlist/?semnr=11091

http://www.dagstuhl.de/program/calendar/partlist/?semnr=10071

and then to look at the publications of each participant on DBLP. This would give you a good overview of who is doing what in the area. (The approach should work also for other topics.)

Answer (score 5):

Kirk Pruhs, Cliff Stein, Kamesh Munagala, Nikhil Bansal, Sungjin Im, Ben Moseley.